# Angular perform recursion to traverse hierarchy structure

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, recursion, tree

I have the following code in which the "currentNode" is the node which has been selected from the hierarchy level. It is a json having key-value pairs. It has keys like "children", "selected" etc.

I want to perform recursion so that whenever a node is selected (the selected function has the "currentNode" which is selected), check if it has children. If not, just pass the currentNode. If it has children, perform recursion to pass the nodes which have "Selected=true" attribute.

In my current code, I am able to get the selected child nodes only up to one level depth.

checkbox-tree.component.ts:

```
import { Component, EventEmitter, Output } from '@angular/core';
import { TreeNode } from './../../dto/TreeNode';
import { BaseTreeComponent } from './../base-tree/base-tree.component';
import { Subject } from 'rxjs/Subject';

import html from './checkbox-tree.component.html';
import css from '../fortune-select.component.css';

@Component({
  selector: 'checkbox-tree',
  template: html,
  styles: [css],
})

export class CheckboxTreeComponent<T> extends BaseTreeComponent<T> {

  //gets called when a node is selected
  public selected():void {

      if(this.currentNode.children.length !== 0) {
      this.currentNode.children.forEach(child => {if(child.selected = true) {
       this.sliceSelected.emit(child);

      //should ideally check again if child has children and if the child nodes are selected

      }})}
      else {
        this.sliceSelected.emit(this.currentNode); 
      }

    if(!this.linked || (this.currentNode.indeterminate && !this.currentNode.selected)) {
      this.dataChangedEvent();
      return;
    }

    this.currentNode.indeterminate = false;
    if(this.singleLevelOnly) {
      this.currentNode.selectChildrenSingleLevel(this.currentNode.selected);
    } else {
      this.currentNode.selectChildren(this.currentNode.selected);
    }

    this.childChanged.emit();
    this.dataChangedEvent();
  }

}
```

Comment: Sounds like you want to implement a [recursive algorithm](https://www.cs.odu.edu/~cs381/cs381content/recursive_alg/rec_alg.html).

Comment: @Zze - Can you help with the given context?

Comment: We're probably going to have to see the code for `TreeNode` and `BaseTreeComponent` to do this correctly.